# Multiple scala calls faster than tail recursive custom function

Tags: list, scala, recursion

I hope this is the right place for this question.

I wrote some code to improve collision detection on a 2D simulation. Part of this algorithm is to associate a list of objects to the specific 2D area where they belong. A function `f: (Seq[Box], Seq[T]) => Map[Box, Seq[T]]`.

I first implemented it with native Scala functions like `map`, `groupBy`, ... but then I needed it to return also Boxes with empty `Seq[T]` and `groupBy` doesn't do that, so I wrote a recursive function that in my view should be faster that the previous one (this might be me not knowing a better way but this is not the main question).

It turns out that my tail recursive implementation is computationally slower than the one using Scala libraries, its execution time grows faster than the other (benchmarked). I don't understand why, can someone point me to the reason?

```
def spreadAcrossFast[T](
  nodes: Seq[Box],
  objects: Seq[T]
) = {
  // I create the pairs (reference box, objects that intersects the box)
  // intersects() is called nodes.size * object.size times
  val assigned = for (
    b ← nodes;
    s ← objects if intersects( b, s )
  ) yield ( b, s )

  // Group by Box and clean the format of the association above
  assigned
    // Should be O(n*Log n)
    .groupBy( _._1 )
    // Maximum nodes.size iterations
    .map { x ⇒
      // Can consider objects.size / nodes.size iterations
      ( x._1, x._2.map( _._2 ) )
    }
}

def spreadAcrossSlow[T](
  nodes: Seq[Box],
  objects: Seq[T],
  compact: Boolean = true   // If compact == true, don't include in the output Box that
) = {                       // have empty content
  @tailrec
  def loop( boxes: Seq[Box], acc: Map[Box, Seq[T]] ): Map[Box, Seq[T]] = boxes match {
    // End of the boxes, return the accumulator
    case Nil ⇒ acc

    // Get the objects that intersect the box and add them to the accumulator
    case b +: bs ⇒
      // Every call it goes through objects.size items
      // intersects() is called nodes.size * object.size times
      val objInBox = objects.filter( intersects( b, _ ) )
      val newAcc = if ( objInBox.isEmpty && compact ) acc else acc + ( ( b, objInBox ) )
      loop( bs, newAcc )
  }

  // nodes.size iterations
  loop( nodes, Map.empty[Box, Seq[T]] )
}
```

`Seq` is an instance of `List`.

From my point of view `spreadAcrossFast` has more iterations than `spreadAcrossSlow` and the most expensive operation, `intersects()`, is called the same number of times, nodes.size * objects.size

**UPDATE:** No luck even with (but the code is cleaner):

```
def spreadAcrossSlow[T: SpatialIndexable](
  nodes: Seq[Box], objects: Seq[T], compact: Boolean
): Map[Box, Seq[T]] = {
  val acc = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Box, Seq[T]]()

  for ( b ← nodes ) {
    val objInBox = objects.filter( intersects( b, _ ) )
    if ( objInBox.nonEmpty || !compact ) acc += ( ( b, objInBox ) )
  }

  acc.toMap
}
```

Comment: it's hard to tell, but one guess is that because of scala library is using local side-effects (like `var`s and mutable buffers) to achieve better performance - you don't notice them outside, so it's still pure but faster. Besides that, `groupBy` returns optimized Map (not the regular one) which is actually a `view`, so it doesn't cross the collection twice when you're doing `.map` after

Comment: For instance, your `acc` creates a new Map every time you do `+` (so for every element). As far as I can recall it, `groupBy` uses temporary mutable buffer to avoid this (a new Map is created per operation, not per element).

Comment: Yes, good guess, but at worse I should have the same complexity, intersects() has to be called always N*M times. And I see no possible optimizations for the recursive function.- UPDATE: Mmm, I will try to use mutables for that. I didn't think of it

Comment: I believe your `acc + smthng` adds one more "times N" in comparision to scala's implementation

Comment: HashMap should add in "effectively constant" time http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html

Comment: You're also doing head/tail decomposition of `Seq`, which is slow if you happen to pass in an `Array` as `WrappedArray`.

Comment: @ColOfAbRiX depends on number of collisions, it might be not "times N" but let's say "times K". Btw, the memory consumption is growing linear because of copying, so it might affect GC for big collections. As I understand your implementation's execution time is growing faster than scala's but it's still polynomial, not exponential?

Comment: I can't say if polynomial or whatever, I would only guess. But definitely first implementation looks linear and the second looks quadratic in the number of `objects`. When home I will try with the mutable implementation and/or maybe with 2 lists and a final merge

Comment: @som-snytt I'm not using `Array` just List, somewhere else `HashSet` and not much more